# xsl:result-document without output description

Tags: xslt

by using those function

```
<xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('output1/','R_msgID_',A,'.xml')" />
<xsl:value-of select="$filename" />  <!-- Creating  -->
<xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" >
```

there apears

> ```
> output1/R_msgID_A.xml
> ```

is it possible not to show that by transformation ?

```
output1/R_msgID_A.xml
```

Comment: where can I edit my question

Comment: You can click the `edit` link that is underneath your question (just below the [xslt] tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you don't have to use `<xsl:value-of select="$filename" />` to elsewhere do `<xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" >` so if the output of `$filename` bothers you then remove or comment out the `xsl:value-of`.